# Sapphire Radeon HD 4870 2GB Vapor-X hashrate

Tags: mining

I want to learn Sapphire Radeon HD 4870 2GB Vapor-X hashrare but there is no info in anywhere.How can I learn that gpu hashrate?

here is some info about that gpu.Can we learn hashrate from core clock or memory clock?I want to use that gpu card for mining

Sapphire Radeon HD 4870 2GB Vapor-X

Manufacturer: Sapphire
Core Clock: 750MHz
Memory Clock: 3,600MHz (effective)
Memory: 2GB GDDR5

Answer (score 0):

It can mine Expanse or Ubiq, ethereum dag size is 2.89 GB at the moment.

At ethereum, the theoretical hashrate at zero-latency is given knowing the memory bandwidth, for me the hashrate was a little bit smaller with another gpu (21 instead of 23)

The formula is: Effective memory clock*Bus width/8/8192
where Effective memory clock is base memory clock or multiplier (2 for gddr3,hbm,hbm2;4 for gddr5;8 for gddr6)
and clock is in Mhz,bus width in bits,the result in MH

At this card the bus width is 256 bit

the zero-latency hashrate is:
3600*256/8/8192=14.0625 MH/s